# Tensorflow: get all tensors beginning with "Add"

Tags: python, tensorflow

Right now I am doing the following to access tensors in my graph

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
add_0 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("Add:0")
add_1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("Add_1:0")
add_2 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("Add_2:0")
```

When the graph is short, this approach is ok. But for longer graphs it gets really boring.

Is there a way to collect all tensors beginning with `Add` in a clean way? Something like:

```
add = []
for Add in graph.get_tensors_by_name():
    add.append(Add)
```

(I know this pseudocode is really wrong)

Such that I get `add = [add_0, add_1, add_2, ... ]`

Later I want to use it to do that: `sess.run(add, feed_dict={input: data})`

Answer (score 2):

You can get all tensors with [`sess.graph.get_operations()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_operations) and then use [`startswith()`](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/startswith.html) to pick the ones you need. Tested code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant( [ 1.0 ] )
b = tf.constant( [ 2.0 ] )
c = tf.add( a, b )
d = tf.add( c, b )

with tf.Session() as sess:

    tensors = sum( [ operation.outputs
                             for operation in sess.graph.get_operations() 
                             if operation.name.startswith( "Add") ],
                   [] )
    print( tensors )
    print( sess.run( tensors ) )
```

Outputs:

> tf.Tensor 'Add:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, tf.Tensor 'Add_1:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32
>   [array([3.], dtype=float32), array([5.], dtype=float32)]

Comment: Why do we need the `sum()` here? Does it help later when I pass the expression `tensors` to `sess.run([tensors], feed_dict{...})`?

Comment: When I am looking for weights in my network which I all labeled starting with `h` like `h1`, `h2` and so on, this approach returns all kind of operations which are linked to the weights. What can I do if I only want to have the weights in a list?

Comment: @Samuel Sum() is needed to convert the list-of-lists into a simple list

Comment: @Samuel I don't know how you named the tensors but you can change the inner condition (where the 'startswith()' is) as you see fit, using maybe 'endswith( "weights" )' or similar.